# Bamboo: pass pom version to child plan in another project

Tags: maven, continuous-integration, bamboo

I use bamboo for my CI. There i have configured a project that contains a plan. This plan checks out a maven project and builds it. When this buid is successful, i start a plan of another project. In this other plan i need to access the maven version of the first plan.
Does anyone know how this is possible?
Problems are the following:

1. extracting the version from the pom.xml
2. passing this value to child plan which is inside another project.

Thanks for your help!